# Implementing another table view in a UITableViewController ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I need to add a new table view to my UITableViewController which will includes a different data and design.

[image]

the above prototype cells is the new table view I've added in storyboard, and the main table view is the second one which includes (title, label, and image).

Is it allowed to create another table view in UITableViewController, or should I create a UIViewController and implement the two tables in it???

In fact, I've finished the implementation of the first table view controller, so I need to implement the new one.

the attached image is showing what I want:
[image]

Comment: You need to develop different kind of cells in one TableView am I right?

Comment: no i need to develop another table view (list of new contents).

Comment: can you attach some examples of design that you need in the end

Comment: Different content but cells design will be the same, am I right?

Comment: the fast news is a table view which includes different data to the the below table view which is sectioned viewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better off with a `UIViewController` that has two `tableViews` as subviews if you want both of your tables to be shown at the same time. `UITableViewController` should be used only when there is just one tableView shown at a certain time.

You can either have one `UIViewController` being the `dataSource` and `delegate` for both of the tableViews, or have a `UITableViewController` for each of your tables and add them as subviews to a `UIViewController` that will be a container view for both of them. The latter will probably save you some time debugging possible issues as having two tableViews with a single `delegate`/`dataSource` requires a lot of duplicate code in the same place.

Comment: how can I rely a UITableViewController to UIViewController as subviews?

Comment: Just instantiate them and add them as subviews, something like:

MyTableViewController *tableVC = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:tableVC.tableView];

This might require some frame adjusting, but it should work (MyTableVC is your tableViewController class that you made yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [UIExpandableTableView](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView)

there is detailed usage on [github page](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView#uiexpandabletableview)

[image: Example of UIExpandableTableView]

Scree example of UIExpandableTableView

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have them be two independent tables, or is it a master/child setup?
If they are independent, I suggestion using one table and two sections, then depending on the section number return to correct cell. 
For master/child, think about making a view that looks like a cell and have the master cells be the sections views and the children be the actually rows.  You can make a section class that stores if the children are visible or not and in the numberOfRowsInSection method return the count if visible or 0 if not.

Just a couple ideas